# understanding the torch.nn.functional.grid_sample op by concrete example

Tags: pytorch, bilinear-interpolation

I am debugging a neural network which has a torch.nn.functional.grid.sample operator inside. Using the Pycharm IDE, I can watch the values during debugging. My grid is a `1*15*2`    tensor, here are the values in the first batch[image].

My input is a `1*128*16*16` tensor, here are the values in the first channel of the first batch:[image].

My output is `1*128*1*15` tensor, here are the values in the first channel of the first batch[image].

align_corners = False, mode = 'bilinear', padding_mode = 'zero'.

For gird coordinates (-1,-1), I can understand that the value(-4.74179) is sampled from 4 values on the top-left corner with 3 of them being the padded '0's and 1 of them being the value '-18.96716'.(-18.96716/4 = -4.74179).

But for other grid coordinates, I am confused. Taking the value '84.65594' for example, it's corresponding grid coordinate is (-0.45302, 0.53659). I firstly convert them from (-1,1) to (0,15) by adding 1 and then dividing by 2 and then multiplying 15(see [official implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/f064c5aa33483061a48994608d890b968ae53fb5/aten/src/THNN/generic/SpatialGridSamplerBilinear.c#L70-L71)). The converted coordinate is then (4.10235, 11.524425), Upon which I see the four values that should be sampled from are :

```
(x)44.20010---0.10235---------(y)26.68777
|             |                    |
|             |                    |
0.524425---(a,b)--------------------
|             |                    |
|             |                    |
(w)102.18765---------------------(z)30.03996
```

here are my calculation by hand step, Let:

```
a = 0.10235
b = 0.524425
x = 44.20010
y = 26.68777
z = 30.03996
w = 102.18765
```

The interpolated value should then be:

```
output = a*b*z + (1 - a)*(1 - b)*x + (1 - a)*b*w + (1-b)*a*y
       = 0.10235*0.524425*30.03996 + (1-0.10235)*(1-0.524425)*44.20010 + (1- 
         0.10235)*0.524425*102.18765 + (1-0.524425)*0.10235*26.68777
       = 69.8852865171
```

which isn't `84.65594`, I cant't figure out how the value '84.65594' in the output is calculated, please help!

Answer (score 2):

I answer my own question, it turns out that the inconsistency is due to the 'align_corners' flag. My way of calculation is actually under the case when 'align_corners' is true while in the program, this flag is set to be false. For how to calculate sample coordinates, please see [this](https://github.com/OrkhanHI/pytorch_grid_sample_python/blob/main/pytorch_grid_sample_python.md)